# CldUploadWidget produces overlay that has an infinite loading spinner

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cloudinary, next.js13

I am trying to use CldUploadWidget of the next-cloudinary package in nextjs13 using the app router.
The idea is upload an image and retrieve the public_id and the url but after setting up, when I click on the button that opens the overlay it opens but I only see a loading spinner that spins infinitely.
The only error/issue I see on the browser (Chrome latest) is the below image:

[error on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ5k2.png)

I have also tested on Safari and I get the same output.

below is my code:

```
"use client";
import Image from "next/image";
import React, { ChangeEvent, useState } from "react";
import styles from "./ImageUpload.module.css";
import { CldUploadWidget } from "next-cloudinary";
import { UploadApiResponse } from "cloudinary";

const ImageUpload = () => {
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const sigApiRoute = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/uploads/signature`;

  const handleImageChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const file = event.target.files && event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      // console.log("File: ", file);
      setSelectedImage(file);
    }
  };

  const onUpload = (response: UploadApiResponse) => {
    console.log(response);
  };

  //   signatureEndpoint={sigApiRoute}
  return (
    <CldUploadWidget uploadPreset="<Upload Preset>">
      {({ open }) => {
        function handleOnClick(
          e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>
        ) {
          e.preventDefault();
          open();
        }
        return (
          <button className="button" onClick={handleOnClick}>
            Upload an Image
          </button>
        );
      }}
    </CldUploadWidget>
  );
};

export default ImageUpload;
```

This is the output: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwjoS.png)

Comment: What is the URL of the page that leads to the 2nd screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwjoS.png) you shared? Are you accessing it via a local HTTP server or opening via the file in the browser directly (i.e. file://..). If it's the latter then that can explain what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

```
    const nextConfig = {
    

    images: {
            domains: ["res.cloudinary.com"]
        },
    }
```

Add this in your next.config.js file and you are done

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but the problem was really funny!
the Environment variable was not written correctly
and the variable had some misspelled words instead of

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME='';
```

and that causes the Cloudinary widget to not recognize the cloud name.